# Pass in Type to check against

Tags: c#, generics, types

I have a method in which I'm doing a check to see if the current object in a loop is the same type as a type I pass into the method.

At first I was passing the type into the method as a string and then using:

```
item.GetType().ToString().Equals(myType);
```

What I'd really prefer to do is use the `is` keyword to do:

```
item is myType
```

The problem I'm having is passing in `myType` to the method. Do I need to use some kind of funky generics type or something? What type do I pass in a reference ot a type as?

Comment: I suggest you just learn generics, it will help you tremendously. The fact that you call them funky tells me that you haven't really understood their usage yet, but they're so pervasive that you basically just need them, sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it something like this?

```
public static bool ContainsType<T>()
{
    object[] objects = new object[] { };

    foreach (var o in objects)
    {
        if (o is T)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ContainsType<int>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the normal equality operator:

```
item.GetType() == myType;
```

This will return `true` if item is of the exact type that myType describes. Note that it will return `false` if there is any difference, though:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }

B item = new B();
Type myType = typeof(A);
bool sameType = item.GetType() == myType; // this will be false
```

One good thing to know about `Type` objects is this text that is to be found [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx):

> A `Type` object that represents a type
>   is unique; that is, two `Type` object
>   references refer to the same object if
>   and only if they represent the same
>   type. This allows for comparison of
>   `Type` objects using reference equality.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
    public List<T> GetItemsOfType<T>(List<object> allObjects)
    {
        return allObjects.Where(o => o is T).Cast<T>().ToList();
    }
```

Which you would then call with something like

```
var result = GetItemsOfType<MyType>(myObjects);
```